# How to copy a view in Interface Builder by Just Dragging Mouse?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

In visual Studio I just press Ctrl while dragging the view. The view gets copied instead of moved.

How do I do the same in Interface Builder at Objective-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can duplicate views if you drag them with alt.

Comment: I think this will only work on elements within a view, not the entire view itself.

Comment: doesn't work on Xcode 5. @RichFox's duplicate will work but as implied, it doesn't duplicate and position.

Comment: It does not copy constraints for all views.

Comment: That's right. The normal thing is that the constraints are changing at least

Comment: doesn't work for me in Xcode 7 and 8. It moves the selected view instead.

Answer (score 9):

command + d will duplicate a view,
although I do not know of a dragging method to do this.